# Using pspdfkit in electron (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, electron, pspdfkit

I would like to use pspdfkit with React in electron. I am not sure how I could do this. I know there is a [React native wrapper available](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/react-native), but I am not sure whether this is of any use to me, since I am not using React *native*, but React & electron.

On the other hand, there seems to be a web version available, but the only example given on their website is with docker. I would like to integrate it into my React / electron app, not have it run on localhost:XXXX in a browser.

Any advice on how I could approach this, generally speaking?

Answer (score 0):

PSPDFKit Founder and CEO here.

What you are looking for is an Offline-Version of [PSPDFKit for Web](https://pspdfkit.com/web/). This is a separate framework that works standalone and doesn't need a Server-Component to render PDF documents. We're already working on that. Stay tuned!

Happy to discuss this more: peter at pspdfkit dot com

Edit: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/other-languages/electron/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. If I would want to use it with electron, would I not have a node server environment ready (albeit on the clients machine)?

Comment: Our Docker server is designed to run on Webservers. There's a license activation and it binds to a specific domain. This alone would prevent use inside an Electron shell, and rightfully so, as it would be really wasteful to run a whole Linux instance just to render PDFs. We're working on something much better and faster for your use case.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the reply. Can you put any (rough) time frame on this?

Comment: Please email me for further details. We're not yet ready for a public announcement.